# using [Authorize] mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, boolean-operations

So at the top of my controllers i've added in [Authorize],
So far so good only logged in users can access these pages (Person and Holiday)

However the tabs in the homeController which navigate the users to these pages are still displayed...coming from the layout.cs

```
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Person", "Index", "Person")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Holidays", "Index", "Holidays")</li>
```

How can I only get these tabs to display if a user is logged in.

I have tried the approach of adding in a bool in the AccountController.cs

```
else
                    {
                        loggedIn = true;
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    loggedIn = false;
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
```

but then how do I access this from the layout.cs?

Is this the correct approach.
Please advise.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
     if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //process here
        }
        else
        {
            //  Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
```